# Azure Application Insights Cloud Role Name to API Management

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-api-management

I tried to search if there is a way to add custom Cloud RoleName for API management resource? We have one Application Insights instance and we have all our applications for that environment use that App Insights instance. The question I have is how do we set a cloud roleName for API Management, I tried searching for it but couldnt find any? Any help on how this can be done? Any documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible today.

API Management is working on the new feature that will allow that - stay tuned for API Management release announcements.

Comment: Thank you Liudmila, appreciate your quick response! So how do we do it currently just use the default name that comes for API Management till the time Microsoft release it?

Comment: Right, this is the only option available at the moment.

Comment: Thank you Liudmila! so basically without the cloud_RoleName I really cant get the Application Map to show the friendly name and also some of the reporting I am building based on cloud_RoleName may not work. any ETA on this releas?